# How to generate and use a detekt baseline using the maven plugin?

Tags: maven, kotlin, detekt

I'm trying to use detekt in a multi-module Maven project using Kotlin with the [detekt-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Ozsie/detekt-maven-plugin).

Following the instructions found [here](https://github.com/Ozsie/detekt-maven-plugin) to generate a baseline with the existing issues, I tried running:

```
mvn detekt:cb -Ddetekt.debug=true
```

This does not seem to produce the mentioned `baseline.xml` file however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the baseline filename must be specified when baseline is generated:

```
mvn detekt:cb -Ddetekt.baseline=baseline.xml
```

Since the code base already had quite a few issues found by detekt, I also had to use a custom detekt config file and increase the number of allowed issues - otherwise the build would fail and no baseline would be generated at all.

To summarize, the following configuration made it work:

detekt config file:

```
build:
  maxIssues: 1000
```

Plugin configuration after the baseline was generated:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.ozsie</groupId>
            <artifactId>detekt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <baseline>detekt-baseline.xml</baseline>
                <config>detekt-config.yml</config>
                <buildUponDefaultConfig>true</buildUponDefaultConfig>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

After the baseline was generated, the `maxIssuses` value in the config file could be lowered to an appropriate value.

Comment: There was no existing tag for detekt-maven-plugin, so maybe someone with higher rep can add one.